# PowerShell OAuth without Internet Explorer

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, oauth, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

I am trying to get an access token in Powershell for Trello by creating a WPF Window with Webbrowser Control like [this](https://github.com/GlobalSign/OAuth-2.0-client-examples/blob/master/PowerShell/Powershell-example.ps1).
Trello blocks logins from Internet Explorer. Is there an alternative Browser or Control i can use and interact with. CefSharp does not seem to work in Powershell.

Comment: Please refer to [this article](https://developers.trello.com/page/authorization#section-using-basic-oauth), the Trello API supports basic OAuth 1.0, Then, you could refer to [this article](https://glitch.com/edit/undefined#!/trello-oauth?path=server.js:1:0) to create an http request with parameters in Powershell, and using the Invoke-RestMethod to send the request and get the response, then, parse the response and get the access token.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT your second link is broken. I think it refers to [https://glitch.com/~trello-oauth](https://glitch.com/~trello-oauth).

Comment: The link is https://glitch.com/edit/#!/trello-oauth?path=server.js:1:0